# Vba do not open wbook

Tags: vba

There isn't enough memory to complete this action" in Excel
How to fix it without opening file
İ want to turn calculation manual but without open it is impossible

Comment: Seems that workbook is broken or Excel installation have to be repaired.

Comment: Other workbook are opening. This one is broken maybe. What does WB broken mean. How can fix it

Comment: You probably cannot fix it if you cannot open it. Try it on another computer. If it does not open there, then there is a high chance it is lost. In this case use your backup. Once you can open it, make sure you copy only the data to a new workbook that you startet from scratch.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ, disagree. There is a chance to repair corrupted workbook. Check out official documentation: [Repair a corrupted workbook](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/repair-a-corrupted-workbook-153a45f4-6cab-44b1-93ca-801ddcd4ea53)

Comment: @MaciejLos You can try your luck but most times Excel just tells it had repaired the workbook but the issue is still there. I never managed to repair a xlsx/xlsm file properly. Especially with heavy data they get easily corrupted. Therefore I only use the binary xlsb format which I never had any corruptions with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to change the automatic calculation to manual without opening the .xlsx file, you can do this. **Before doing this, be sure to make a copy of the file and try these manipulations on the copy.**
Unzip the .xlsx as a .zip archive, open the file `...\xl\workbook.xml` in a text editor, find a tag similar to the following `<calcPr calcId="191029"/>` and add to it `calcMode="manual"` so you get `<calcPr calcId="191029" calcMode="manual"/>`. Then save this file, package the entire directory, and change the extension to .xlsx.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Unzip the .xlsx as a .zip archive, open the file ...\xl\workbook.xml...what you mean by it

Comment: The `.xlsx` file is a `.zip` archive, but with a `.xlsx` extension. Change the `.xlsx` extension to `.zip` and work with the Excel file as a `.zip` archive, which contains files and subdirectories, including the `workbook.xml` file. If you use Total Commander, for example, you can "fall" inside the `.xlsx` file simply by pressing `Ctrl+PageDown` on it.